# Managing multiple makefiles in vim

Tags: vim, makefile

I would like to effectively manage different project in Vim. When it is time to rebuild I have several Makefiles in different locations. In Vim if I use `:make` it will try to compile the Makefile in my current location.

I can use or `:make -f URL-MAKEFILE` but it's too much work. Is there a way or a plugin to build all those separate makefile in an efficient way without me remebering all Makefile url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if there is a such plugin, but you can create a kind of a shortcuts for your URLs.
Create main makefile and add targets such:

```
.PHONY : shortcut
      make -f URL target
```

Afterwards you can just call `:make shortcut`

Comment: This is the way I like! Very easy to remember. Thanks!

Comment: p.s. In case I want to do a 'make clean'  I need to have a dedicated command for each project. Is what you do as well?

Comment: You can call several commands for each target, i.e. 
.PHONY : clean;  
    make -f prj1_makefile clean;  
    make -f prj2_makefile clean;
P.S. consider ";" as newline

Comment: Simple and nice one, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can instruct vim to find a "Makefile" file upwards in your directory structure, then call :make with it

```
:exec ":make -f " . findfile("Makefile", ".;")
```

That way it will call the Makefile related to the project tree of the buffer currently open.

However, I'd advise not to use make -f path_to_makefile that much, because it launches the make command inside the directory where you are. Usually Makefiles are written to be used at the top of your project tree (and then eventually call more Makefile in the subdirectories), so it's more natural to call "make -C path_to_top_of_tree"

To find the first directory upward with a Makefile in it then call :make -C with it:

```
:exec ":make -C " . fnamemodify(findfile("Makefile", ".;"), ":h")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm maintaining multiple projects, each one having its own makefile with one of the numerous [local_vimrc](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/plugin/local_vimrc.vim) scripts.

Actually I'm also encapsulating the update of the `&makeprg` option with my [BuildToolsWrapper](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/BTW/trunk/lh-build-tools-wrapper-addon-info.txt) plugin (prefer Vim-Addons-Manager to install it). It goes further and enables me to choose the compilation directory and other options (which is quite useful when the makefile has been generated with CMake). See the two *.vim files [here to see how I configure my projects](https://github.com/LucHermitte/Rasende).